# Swapping between the inner exception and message property if there was "see the inner exception for details" message?

Tags: c#, exception

I want to grab the exception details to show it in `alert` message (for developers) but for some exceptions these details aren't in the `Message` property:

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception
>   for details

So is there a way to get the full description of the exception (since the *compiler*(?) know what is the helpful details for me)?

Comment: You've basically just asked the same question again after your [previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42673972/how-to-get-the-exception-message-that-i-dont-know-if-it-exists-in-the-message-p) was closed.

Comment: @DavidG You think, it's the same?!

Comment: Considering @Tim's answer to this and to the deleted question are basically the same, then YES!

Comment: Yes the same for me, but more clearer, unless  you have a problem with the question itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want the `InnerException.Message` if there is one, otherwise the `Exception.Message`:

```
string exMsg = ex.InnerException?.Message ?? ex.Message;
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought there might be a *hidden* property for getting the "details" of an exception

Comment: @MohamedAhmed: you can use `ex.ToString()` to get all details, the exception type, the message,  stack trace(including line numbers), and all these again for all inner exceptions.